# Is it possible to have typescript output in different file extension

Tags: c#, javascript, typescript

I have file with the extension .jsv that a actually just javascript files but the application using the file requires them to be with the .jsv extension. The project is a c# library project with these files. I want to try and migrate to typescript. I want to add a file like `file1.ts` and have typescript generate `file1.jsv` as I make changes. Is this possible and if yes, how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `--out` flag to achieve this if you are using the TypeScript compiler:

```
tsc --out app.jsv  app.ts
```

This results in the output going to `app.jsv` (but it will also combine your output into a single file where it detects dependencies).

Otherwise you could run a post-build event to rename all your `*.js` to `*.jsv`.

Comment: I'm doing it from visual studio. All .jsv files are currently in the folder ``content\views``. How do I use tsc from visual studio? Or I have to use the post-build event? What will this look like?

Comment: You should be able to set an out file in Project Properties > TypeScript Build. Just right click the project file and select "Properties". You can also add the post build event there - it just runs a command (like you would in comment prompt): `ren *.js *.jsv`

Comment: If I did it right, it appears in the first case, it will just combine all the files as one and that is not what I'm looking for. I tested the post build event and I'm getting and error but it could be due to me not using the ren command correctly. Checking online for more details. I use the command below to rename all js files in the views folder to jsv: ``ren "$(SolutionDir)views\*.js" "$(SolutionDir)views\*.jsv"``